# Heuristic for large $x$ behavior from small $q$ behavior of Fourier Transform

Tags: field-theory, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, fourier-transform, mathematics, asymptotics

> If I have a function $h(\mathbf x)$ which may be written
>
> $$h(\mathbf x)= \int \frac{\text{d}^d\mathbf q}{(2\pi)^d} \, h(\mathbf q) e^{-i \mathbf q \cdot \mathbf x}$$
>
> and assume spherical symmetry, is there way to determine the large $x$ behavior of $h(x)$ from the small $q$ behavior of $h(q)$ without computing the integral? Assume nice "physics" functions-- and further assume, if useful, that $h(x)$ has power-law or exponential asymptotics.

Motivation:

The motivation for this question is understanding the real-space asymptotics of various propagators/ correlators in QFT and statistical field theory.

Guesses:

Suppose for instance $h(q) \sim q^{-k}$ as $q\to 0$. Then the RHS scales as $q^{d-k}$ for small $q$ and I may expect that $h(x) \sim x^{k-d}$ for large $x$. I expect this doesn't work in general, since $\frac{1}{q^2+m^2}$ Fourier transforms to an exponential. For a better answer, perhaps there is a way to expand $h(q)$ in Laurent series near $q=0$ and Fourier transform term-by-term... and then attempt to sum the series to see exponential behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the derivatives of $h(q)$, you can exponentiate it to
$$
S_{d-2}\int_0^\pi d\theta\,\sin^{d-2}\theta\int \frac{d q}{(2\pi)^d}\, q^{d-1}\exp\left(\log h(q) - i qx\cos\theta\right)\,,
$$
where $S_{d-2}$ is the volume of the $d-2$-dimensional sphere. After performing the integral in $d\theta$ (which doesn't require the knowledge of $h(q)$), you'll obtain an expression of the form
$$
I(x)=\int dq\,F(q) \,\exp\left(G(q) - i q x\right)\,.
$$
At this point there is a systematic procedure for approximating this integral, which is called either [Stationary phase approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation) or [Method of steepest descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent).

At the lowest order you just have to expand the exponential to quadratic order around the point that has zero first derivative. Then you evaluate $F(q)$ at this point and evaluate the Gaussian integral.

$$
\begin{aligned}
I(x) &\sim \int dq F(q_0) \exp\left(G(q_0) - i q_0 x + \tfrac12 (q-q_0)^2 G''(q_0) \right) =
\\&=
F(q_0) \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{x\, G''(q_0)}}\exp\left(G(q_0) - i q_0 x\right)\,.
\end{aligned}
$$
This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it's an idea.